# What is the best way to design routes? Is it good to have multiple routes?

Tags: routes, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am using JBoss Fuse and i am confused should i have multiple route or one single route. Lets say we have 2 conditions and we are going to perform different action based on condition. For example

```
<camelContext>
<route>
<choice>
<onWhen>
<simple>${property.name} == 'foo'</simple>
....do something
</onWhen>
<onWhen>
<simple>${property.name} == 'bar'</simple>
...do something
</onWhen>
</route>
</camelContext>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no a single valid answer for this kind of questions, since it depends a lot on your application. Generally speaking, having smaller routes makes it easy to *test* your application and *reuse* logic.

You can refactor your route like this

```
<camelContext>
    <route>
        <!-- route starts somehow -->
        <choice>
            <onWhen>
                <simple>${property.name} == 'foo'</simple>
                <to uri="direct:handleFoo" />
            </onWhen>
            <onWhen>
                <simple>${property.name} == 'bar'</simple>
                <to uri="direct:handleBar" />
            </onWhen>
        </choice>
    </route>

    <route id="ThisRouteWillHandleFooCase">
        <from uri="direct:handleFoo" />
        <to uri="..." />
        <!-- do stuff for foo here -->
    </route>

    <route id="ThisOtherRouteIsForBarCase">
        <from uri="direct:handleBar" />
        <to uri="..." />
        <!-- do stuff for bar here" -->
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

The `direct:` component makes it like calling a Java method, it's a direct and synchronous call to the other route. Now you can easily test the behaviour for **foo** and the behaviour for **bar**.

Now imagine that you need to update a database or make a web service call very often: it's better to have a single route that does the job and calling it multiple times.

Comment: Thanks a lot your answer is very much clear, but i was wondering if using direct is efficient or not? how does it work in background? i want to make my code easy for unit testing but i refrain from using direct because i dont know how exactly it works